# java.nio.file.FileSystemException in elasticsearch-plugin list command

Tags: elasticsearch-plugin

I am using `elasticSearch  7.10.1`, `elasticSearch-analysis-ik 7.10.1`. When I use `elasticsearch-plugin list` to check the plugin list, I got the error of

```
.DS_Store
Exception in thread "main" java.nio.file.FileSystemException: /Users/qiangyao/workspace/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-7.10.1/plugins/.DS_Store/plugin-descriptor.properties: Not a directory
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:100)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:106)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:111)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:218)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:375)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:426)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.spi.FileSystemProvider.newInputStream(FileSystemProvider.java:420)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.newInputStream(Files.java:160)
    at org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginInfo.readFromProperties(PluginInfo.java:156)
    at org.elasticsearch.plugins.ListPluginsCommand.printPlugin(ListPluginsCommand.java:66)
    at org.elasticsearch.plugins.ListPluginsCommand.execute(ListPluginsCommand.java:60)
    at org.elasticsearch.cli.EnvironmentAwareCommand.execute(EnvironmentAwareCommand.java:86)
    at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:127)
    at org.elasticsearch.cli.MultiCommand.execute(MultiCommand.java:91)
    at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:127)
    at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:90)
    at org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginCli.main(PluginCli.java:47)
```

Other `elasticsearch-plugin` works fine. I followed the instruction from here https://github.com/medcl/elasticsearch-analysis-ik

Answer (score 1):

The problem is solved by removing the `.DS_Store` file in the `plugins` folder.

Answer (score 1):

mac os created a .DS_Store hidden folder when we browse directories it via finder. Do not browse directories and .DS_Store will not be created.
To remove use this command :

```
sudo find /Path/to/your/elasticsearch-folder -name ".DS_Store" -depth -exec rm {} \;
```